# Income Tax Germany-UK - Different tax years

Tags: taxes, income, germany

I've recently moved to Germany, how can I incorporate my earnings from the UK into German income tax system when the tax years are different?

German tax year (Calender year)
UK tax year (April-April)

I am negotiating terms of an employment contract to fall below the low income threshold in Germany (8,354 Euros), but I was working in the UK previously this year from February-April. So I want to calculate how much I can earn and still be below the income tax threshold

Many thanks,
Apologies if not clear.
Will

Comment: Could you explain _why_ you want to stay below this threshold? Generally, the more money you make, the better.